# Config is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have **config.js** file in my project with next.js (redux direcrories) and the line in it:

```
declare var __CONFIG__: Object;
```

but when I run my localhost, I received error:

```
__CONFIG__ is not defined in .next/dist/lib/config.js
```

Next.js converted my file and I received the changing result in **config.js**:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
```

instead of:

```
declare var __CONFIG__: Object;
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you.